# Is it possible to bind an Angular Component to an array of callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular component that displays list items.

I would like each list item to have a set of menu buttons that call various functions on the parent component/controller

Is it possible to have a component binding that takes an array like this:

```
[
    {Name: 'Edit', Callback: editItem(item)},
    {Name: 'Delete', Callback: deleteItem(item)},
    {Name: 'Add', Callback: addItem(item)},
]
```

Then my component template can just do an ng-repeat on the array to display the appropriate buttons with their click action.

I have tried setting up the binding as such but it does not seem to work:

```
binding = {
    actions: '&'
}
```

Comment: your callback is already executing unless it returns an anoymous function

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, but you can:

Define object, with whatever number of function fields, etc:

```
function test() {}
actions = {
  foo : test, foos : [test, test, test]
}
```

And pass it using 2-way binding: `actions: '='`
Here you do not care about args and you call callback in component 
like `actions.foos[1](p1, p2, p3)`